# Where can I change the row width and gutter used by the small grid in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation

I see these settings for the regular grid (default at 1000px and with 30px gutters), but these are obviously different when using the small grid. How are these determined?

I do notice that these values are set using Zurb's emCalc function which converts the pixels into em units. Does this mean there is no setting for the small grid and it just scales these down?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few pointers to begin with ...

- 1000px is the `width` but the `max-width` is set to 100% which means the `.row` containers will squash when the windows is less that 1000px (`max-width` takes precedence)
- The gutter does not change
- Em unit do not scale with browser window size which is what Zurb Foundation switches on.
- All the `emCalc` does is divide px values by 16 to get the em value (or multiply em values by 16 to get the px value) since most browsers use size 16px font - this conversion is basically hardcoded in the Sass file, not sniffed from the browser or anything super smart like that.

So from what I can gather ...

- Each `columns` div in the grid has margins of half the gutter width - when the divs sit side by side they make a full gutter
- It avoids indentation at the outer edges by making the `row` boxes slightly wider than 1000px by one gutter width - this swallows the extra half gutters on the outermost edges
- When switching to the small size, all that changes is that each `columns` div now spans 12 spaces - the overhang is still there just as before

Hope that helps!